# How to pull this information

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, powerapp

In SharePoint I can set my "Created By" column to display as "Office", which then shows as this.

[image]

My problem is, that I cannot figure out a way to pull what is displayed here to use for a condition in a flow.

SharePoint will not allow me to use "Created By" in a calculated column.

Also nowhere in the flows dynamic content is there a "Created By Office".

Does anyone have any ideas? Please, I have been on this for days now.

Answer (score 0):

May be, write a sharepoint designer workflow that will copy text from Created by and copy it to another new text field on item creation.

Once copied, use this new field in your flow for calculation.

Sequence of sharepoint designer and flow trigger can get tricky, so you might want to play around by carrying some tests, to make sure field is updated first and then Flow triggers.

Comment: I will attempt this. Unfortunately I am having an issue with SharePoint Designer on my companies network. So I will have to get that resolved first.

Comment: Looks like SharePoint designer is un usable on my companies machines as they all use Office 2016 64bit. Which from my understanding and after multiple attempts cannot co exist with SharePoint designer. Do you have any ideas for an alternative solution?

Comment: how about 64bit sharepoint designer? its strange. I have office 2016 on multiple machines and every machine ahs designer as well. one of the version should get installed (either 32 or 64)